# How to check if user is logged in or not with Cartalyst Sentry2 Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I wanted to put feature in my application that if user is already logged in & If user try to log In from different browser or computer then he should get notification message about that "Do he want to login here & terminate other session ? In "Yes" case it should be Sentry's default process but in "No" case user should again redirect to login page.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What's the version of your laravel?

Comment: Laravel version is 4.2 .